# Query with permutation of combinations

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name 
WHERE column1='yes' AND column2='yes'
```

if u see above both column1,column2 are yes now i want reslut set with all the combinations i..e, column1,column2 are No ,column1='yes' and column2='no' etc.. that is permutation of columns

instead of writing 6 queries

Comment: Do you really need `SELECT *`?

Comment: this seems to be done by select * from tbl_name unless if your column1 and column2 may have null.Is that the condition??

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any other values that can appear in `column1` and `column2`, then you should be able to use:

```
select * 
from tbl_name
```

But if you have other values in those columns, then you can use:

```
select * 
from tbl_name 
where column1 in ('yes', 'no')
  and column2 in ('yes', 'no')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd503/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tbl_name
```

This will give you all the records, ofcourse this will contain all the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

to find all the unique combinations of those 2 columns existing in your table you use DISTINCT or GROUP BY

eg

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2 FROM tbl_name
```

or

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM tbl_name GROUP BY column1, column2
```